# Javascript: prompting and printing with for loops

Tags: javascript

JavaScript: Specifically using 2 for loops: First for loop, prompt the user for 3 names. Second for loop, print out those 3 names.

I can do this with a single for loop but how do I complete the task with 2 separate for loops?

```
    var i = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var name = prompt("Please enter a name");
        document.write(name + "<br/>");
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an array to store the values entered in the first loop and print the values

```
var i, array = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var name = prompt("Please enter a name");
    array.push(name);
}
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    document.write(array[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold the values getting from the first for loop, in order to use it later. So for holding the values you have to use an [ARRAY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```
  var i = 1,xArray=[];

    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        xArray[xArray.length] = prompt("Please enter a name");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
        document.write(xArray[i] + "<br/>");
    }
```

[use Array[Array.length] to stuff values in to the arrays](http://jsperf.com/push-vs-length-test)